# Reading Two Data Models from Firebase Swift

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, denormalization

I have two models: a `User` model and a book `Review` model. My `username` in the Review is of type `User` so that I can retrieve a given review and the user who created it.

I can now retrieve the Review but **not** the User object with my code. What am I doing wrong?

**User Class**

```
class User: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var profileImageUrl: String?
    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
        self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
    }
}
```

**Review Struct**

```
struct Review {
    let id: String
    let bookName: String
    let author: String
    let review: String
    let username: User
    let createdAt: Date
    init(id: String, bookName: String, author: String, review: String, username: User, timestamp: Double) {

        self.id = id
        self.bookName = bookName
        self.author = author
        self.review = review
        self.username = username
        self.createdAt = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp / 1000)
    }
}
```

**Review Controller**

```
 private func fetchReviews() {
    let reviewRef = Database.database().reference().child("reviews")
    let queryRef = reviewRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryLimited(toLast: 5)

    queryRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        var temporaryReviews = [Review]()

        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let dictionary = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                let user = dictionary["user"] as? [String:Any],
                let id = user["id"] as? String,
                let name = user["name"] as? String,
                let profileImageUrl = user["profileImageUrl"] as? String,
                let url = URL(string: profileImageUrl),
                let bookName = dictionary["bookName"] as? String,
                let author = dictionary["author"] as? String,
                let review = dictionary["review"] as? String,
                let timestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as? Double {

                let user = User(dictionary: <#T##[String : AnyObject]#> ??? // Cannot use a user object

                let review = Review(id: childSnapshot.key, bookName: bookName, author: author, review: review, username: user, timestamp: timestamp)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    temporaryReviews.insert(review, at: 0)
                    self.reviews = temporaryReviews
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

If I remove the user and its associating values from the loop, I get the data in the UI but no `username` or `photoImageURL` which I am updating in my view class. The data is already in Firebase. How can I read the data and the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what is expected of this line

```
let user = User(dictionary: <#T##[String : AnyObject]#> ???
```

and also not sure why class User: NSObject is an NSObject but this will work with Swift 5.

```
class User { //using pure Swift, remove NSObject
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var profileImageUrl: String?
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) { //change AnyObject to Any
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
        self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
    }
}
```

then when reading the Firebase data in the closure create a Dictionary of the items you want to populate the user class with

```
let id = user["id"] as? String,
let name = user["name"] as? String,
let profileImageUrl = user["profileImageUrl"] as? String,
let url = URL(string: profileImageUrl),

let dict: [String: Any] = [
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "email": email,
    "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl
]

let aUser = User(dictionary: dict)
```

Or you could just pass the snapshot to the User class and let it get whatever it needs from it

```
class User {
    var user_id = ""
    var name = ""
    var email = ""
    var profileImageUrl = ""

    init(withSnap: DataSnapshot) {
        self.user_id = withSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "id").value as? String ?? "No Id"
        self.name = withSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? "No name"
        self.email = withSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as? String ?? "No email"
        self.profileImageUrl = withSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as? String ?? "No url"
    }
}
```

and then

```
let aUser = User(withSnap: snapshot)
```

Also, in your code, the tableView is being reloaded each loop iteration and that may cause flicker. Best bet is to move the `self.tableView.reloadData()` outside the for loop so it only executes once.

Comment: I updated the `User`. No NSObject subclass and I initialized it `[String:Any]`. Also removed the `self.tableView.reloadData` from the forLoop. I added the dictionary - which is similar to what I already had - and I am returning nothing. I can only read data in the app if I remove the user from the forLoop but, of course, I get no user, just the reviews they create.

Comment: This works. Had to remove the email as it's not being created when I initially set the value. Also needed to call `profileImageUrl.loadingImageUsingCache(_:)` in my `cellForRowat(_:)`. I can't publicly upvote it as I am under 15 reputation points. But I will when that changes **Thanks, Jay**

Comment: Done. Thanks, again :)